# Android: make a call and disconnect after ringing to leave a missed call

Tags: android

I am using this code to make call

```
Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL,
                                  Uri.parse("tel:" + phoneNumber));
startActivity(callIntent);
```

and I want to disconnect call after hear first ringing to leave a miss call on the destination  phone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe that's currently available in the Android sdk.  I was trying to control outgoing calls on a project recently but other than dialing a number there's not a lot you can do.  My last project needed to place a call, press a button, then hangup.  For that I ended up setting up an Asterisk server that listened to a web page.  You could do something similar but that would involve using a data connection to your own server.

You can check out these links.  I don't like this answer but it's the way it is for now.

[How to make a phone call in android and come back to my activity when the call is done?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1556987/how-to-make-a-phone-call-in-android-and-come-back-to-my-activity-when-the-call-i)

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_CALL

If you want to step outside of techniques I would recommend check out the [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/599443/android-how-to-hang-up-outgoing-call).