# Cancel an unanswered phone call after a period of time

Tags: android

In Android, I make an outgoing phone call without any user interaction. If the call is not answered within a specific amount of time, I want to cancel the call. I can't find a way to cancel the call.

Answer (score 0):

`telephonyService.endCall();` if you're using this, which I believe is the case. If not, please paste your code here.

Cheers

Comment: This is not a public API. Reflection technique should be used to get this function.

Comment: Please give an example of that. Can you give a suggestion here without knowing the code?

Comment: Take a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/599443/hang-up-outgoing-call-in-android) I think that the first answer is giving the key.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code to drop incoming  call , you will get a notification about the phone state following that please that whether the call is picked or not and drop the call [Here](http://androidsourcecode.blogspot.in/2010/10/blocking-incoming-call-android.html)

Use Timer Inside the broadcast receiver to monitor the minimum interval and then after the interval passed away check whether the call was picked or not and act correspondingly .use timer or Exceutor or Handler to implement the delay .

Comment: That's for incoming calls. I need to terminate an outgoing call.

Comment: <action android:name="android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL"/> add this intent filter to your broadcast receiver and do listen for out going action through intent and then use the same code to end the call after the requisite delay