# How do I know who ended the call in Android - User or Remote User?

Tags: android, android-intent

I want to specifically know who ended the call.  I have setup a broadcast receiver for

```
"android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE"
```

When I detect a transition from **Off hook** to **idle**, I know the call has ended. But how do I know who ended the call?

Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm afraid there's presently no way to determine if the user pressed "end call" or if the other end (or ends, in a group call) terminated. The only workaround I can suggest is monitoring the other states to observe if the phone state *ringing* was encountered. In such a case, you could assume the user is making the phone call as opposed to receiving it.

Bear in mind that there are other problems related to PHONE_STATE, such as handling multiple calls simultaneously.

In retrospect, I'm not entirely sure what you mean with "who". As for other apps ending the call: there is no official API to end phone calls; [only through reflection](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5314372/154306) can an app invoke the TelephonyService's `endCall()` function. Here, too, it is not possible to determine if the call was terminated through user interaction or not.