# Automatic Voice Message during Phone call

Tags: java, android, text-to-speech

I am developing an Android app with java.

I was curious if it is possible to have an automatic voice message ("Help, I Need an Ambulance") during a phone call. I understand that once you call the phone call method it leaves the application to make a phone call. Is it possible to run a text-to-speech function while the phone call is in progress? That way the phone call can pick up the audio from the text-to-speech function during the phone call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, I'm afraid this isn't possible.

There is no audio interface for phone calls, nor any other interface for interacting with telephony. Even something as relatively straight-forward as sending DTMF tones isn't possible without specifically entering them as part of the number to dial, and a basic operation such as hanging up the call [is only possible through hidden interfaces](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5314372/154306).

(While there is [AudioManager.STREAM_VOICE_CALL](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html#STREAM_VOICE_CALL), it can only be used to regulate the in-call volume.)