# How to programmatically hang up a call on Oreo and above?

Tags: java, android, permissions

I am building an application that provides a way for users to block all incoming calls once they activate service.

There is a clear lack of solutions to the problem when it comes to targeting newer SDK versions, in my case Oreo and above. The closest I have been to a solution is [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47731725/how-to-end-an-incoming-call-programmatically-on-android-8-0-oreo) but there is no accepted answer to the question, nor do any of the provided answers work in my case.

Here are just some of the links that I have also visited:

- [How to hang up outgoing call in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/599443/how-to-hang-up-outgoing-call-in-android)
- [Can I hang up a call programmatically in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23097944/can-i-hang-up-a-call-programmatically-in-android)
- [End call in android programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18065144/end-call-in-android-programmatically)
- [How to make a native Android app that can block phone calls](https://dev.to/hitman666/how-to-make-a-native-android-app-that-can-block-phone-calls--4e15)
- [Detecting Incoming and Outgoing Phone Calls on Android](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/548416/Detecting-Incoming-and-Outgoing-Phone-Calls-on-And)

My approach is to use the foreground service and listen to phone call state changes.

```
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    telephonyManager.listen(new CallStateListener(), PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);
    Log.d(TAG, "Called onCreate() method");
}
```

where this is the CallStateListener

```
private class CallStateListener extends PhoneStateListener {
    @Override
    public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String phoneNumber) {
        if (state == TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Phone is ringing");
            TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
            try {
                //Gain access to ITelephony getter
                Class c = Class.forName(telephonyManager.getClass().getName());
                Method method = c.getDeclaredMethod("getITelephony");
                method.setAccessible(true);
                com.android.internal.telephony.ITelephony telephony = (ITelephony) method.invoke(telephonyManager);

                //Hung up the call
                telephony.endCall();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Exception occurred: " + e.getMessage());
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I can confirm that the log message `Phone is ringing` is received

The exception I obtain is `Exception occurred: MODIFY_PHONE_STATE permission required.`

Permission `MODIFY_PHONE_STATE` is not available to third-party application developers. I have seen a suggestion to modify the linter, which I did, but I still cannot request this permission and so the exception persists.

Is there an alternative way to hang up calls in these SDK versions? If so, I would love to be appointed in the right direction. Thank you.